# can I apply list range as a function?

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell.

I know that I can use a tuple operator as a function: `(,) 1 2`.

Can I do the same with the list range `..`? As in `[0..9]`. Or is it not a function?

Basically I have two values that I need to create a list from. The explicit lambda expression works: `\x y -> [x..y]`. I was trying to figure out how to make it shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this with `..`, as it's a syntactic element built into the language rather than a function.  However, there *is* a function that does the same thing as "`(..)`" or your `\x y -> [x..y]` would do: [`enumFromTo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:enumFromTo).

Comment: I believe `"(..)"` is explicitly defined as `enumFromTo`. If you make your own `enumFromTo` function, haskell will use it anytime you do `[x..y]`.

Comment: @PyRulez In standard Haskell, you cannot define your own standalone `enumFromTo` and have it used this way. You have to define an `Enum` class instance for your type. The `RebindableSyntax` extension allows redefining e.g. `>>=`, but doesn't seem to work for `enumFromTo` yet.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen When defining an `Enum` instance, you can define a `enumFromTo`.

Answer (score 4):

Its `enumFromTo`:

```
Prelude> :t enumFromTo
enumFromTo :: Enum a => a -> a -> [a]
Prelude> enumFromTo 1 5
[1,2,3,4,5]
```